# Javascript split() not working! completely stumped

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, console.log

```
filename = "file_1";
name = filename.split('_');
test1 = name[0];
test2 = name[1];
console.log(test1);
console.log(test2);
```

Expected Result:

```
file
1
```

Actual Result:

```
f
i
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j667q/1/

I must be doing something wrong, but can't for the life of me work out what.

I have tried:

- Using different quotes ' and "
- Defining filename and name before using (filename = '';
  name = [];)
- Spliting using a different character ('-')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, something to do with **global conflicts** the global object has a property called name and is somehow conflicting with your code.

rename it http://jsfiddle.net/j667q/3/

you could do `var name = ...split...` if you don't want to rename it

Yeah, also note, you should **ALWAYS** declare variables with `var` there is no reason not to, if you want a global property do `window.someName = something;`

Comment: I agree with renaming, though he should be declaring his variables with `var` regardless of whether there are naming conflicts or not.

Answer (score 3):

Define the array variable first:

```
var name = [];
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/j667q/5/

**Why this works?**

Update for more clarification based on comments:

Although `name` is not a reserved word, it's a global property of `window` (eg. `window.name` and `name` mean the same), `var name;` will define a new variable called `name` which is in another scope and avoids the conflict.

JavaScript Reserved words: http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: It has nothing to do with being an array `var name;` would work just fine

Comment: It doesn't have to be declared ahead of time. Simply adding `var ` at the beginning of line 2 fixes the issue. Also, your suggested fix creates an unused array, so I would say it's bad advice.

Comment: Although, this will solve the problem, this answer gives a wrong idea that its because of missing variable declaration (esp. for people coming from languages where you have to declare a variable first). More appropriate answer would be the one that speaks of conflict.

Answer (score 0):

name is a js global property. so try not to use it. hope that will help

Comment: You're on the right track, however it's not a **keyword** it's a global property

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables as var to scope them properly

```
var filename = "file_1";
var names = filename.split('_');
test1 = name[0];
test2 = name[1];
console.log(test1);
console.log(test2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare both variables like this.

```
var filename = "file_1";
var name = filename.split('_');
```

check out the updated **JSFIDDLE** (**http://jsfiddle.net/prakashcbe/j667q/17/**)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
Other answers all are correct. I don't know your mistake. Anyway, try this as well

[http://jsfiddle.net/puvanarajan/Nytgh/][1]